# What does "Tensorflow: Failed to get CPU frequency: 0Hz" mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I am getting started with tensor flow and I have the following messages I am trying to understand:

`2022-09-12 09:58:48.355646: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:128] Failed to get CPU frequency: 0 Hz 2022-09-12 09:58:48.548392: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:113] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.`

I am running on M1 and installed tensorflow following these steps:

https://betterdatascience.com/install-tensorflow-2-7-on-macbook-pro-m1-pro/

I am trying to understand if these messages are normal or if I have to fix something in my setup. Especially the frequency 0Hz message. Can somebody help me understand why I am getting these messages and tell me if I need to make changes in my setup? Is this normal?

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, let me know when you fix this.